# Custom Dialog, setContentView throws ResourceNotFoundException

Tags: android, dialog, android-resources, r.java-file

I'm using [this tutorial](http://androidexample.com/Custom_Dialog_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=88&aaid=111) to create a custom dialog which should be shown when I click on the "Create New Folder" from a spinner. I get inside the OnItemsSelected method, I check "Create New Folder" option was clicked, and then I want to show a dialog to introduce the name of the new folder. I'm doing it like this:

**res/layout/dialog.html**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/dialog"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:visibility="visible" >

<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/editText_dialog"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:hint="@string/editText_dialog"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"/>

<Button 
    android:id="@+id/button_create_dialog"
    android:text="@string/button_create_dialog"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/editText_dialog"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dip"
    android:background="#176CEC"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>

<Button 
    android:id="@+id/button_cancel_dialog"
    android:text="@string/button_cancel_dialog"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/editText_dialog"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="50dip"
    android:background="#176CEC"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Java File**

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id){
    if (parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString().matches("Create New Folder")){
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
        try {
            dialog.setContentView(R.id.dialog);
            dialog.setTitle("Create New Folder");
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            StringWriter errors = new StringWriter();
            e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(errors));
            Log.i("Exception", errors.toString());
        }


        Button createButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_create_dialog);
        Button cancelButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_cancel_dialog);

        createButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                EditText newFolderName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_dialog);
                String folderName = newFolderName.getText().toString().trim();
                if (folderName.length() > 0) {
                    // do stuff
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });

        cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        dialog.show();
    }
}
```

I'm getting a ResourceNotFoundException. This is the stackTrace:

```
11-07 17:11:49.075: I/Exception(8315): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f05000e
11-07 17:11:49.075: I/Exception(8315):  at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1118)
11-07 17:11:49.075: I/Exception(8315):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2304)
11-07 17:11:49.075: I/Exception(8315):  at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:934)
11-07 17:11:49.075: I/Exception(8315):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:395)
11-07 17:11:49.075: I/Exception(8315):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
11-07 17:11:49.075: I/Exception(8315):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:267)
11-07 17:11:49.075: I/Exception(8315):  at android.app.Dialog.setContentView(Dialog.java:471)
11-07 17:11:49.075: I/Exception(8315):  at com.example.example.MainActivity.onItemSelected(MainActivity.java:94)
11-07 17:11:49.075: I/Exception(8315):  at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:892)
11-07 17:11:49.075: I/Exception(8315):  at android.widget.AdapterView.access$200(AdapterView.java:49)
11-07 17:11:49.075: I/Exception(8315):  at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:860)
11-07 17:11:49.075: I/Exception(8315):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
11-07 17:11:49.075: I/Exception(8315):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-07 17:11:49.075: I/Exception(8315):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-07 17:11:49.075: I/Exception(8315):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
11-07 17:11:49.075: I/Exception(8315):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-07 17:11:49.075: I/Exception(8315):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
11-07 17:11:49.075: I/Exception(8315):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
11-07 17:11:49.075: I/Exception(8315):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-07 17:11:49.075: I/Exception(8315):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

As you can imagine, the resource ID #0x7f05000e matches R.id.dialog, I've checked it:

**inside R.java**

```
 public static final int dialog = 0x7f05000e;
```

Any idea what can be the problem?

**UPDATE**
I forgot to say the Exception is thrown on this line:

```
dialog.setContentView(R.id.dialog);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurred because you try to do `findViewById` on `view(s)` that **not** exists in your `Activity`, but exists in your dialog.

Change this code :

```
    Button createButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_create_dialog);
    Button cancelButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_cancel_dialog);
```

To :

```
    Button createButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button_create_dialog);
    Button cancelButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button_cancel_dialog);
```

Those buttons are not in the `Activity`, so you **cant** just call `findViewById` because it will try to find the `button's` id in the `Activity's` XML. Instead, call `dialog.findViewById` to tell the code to find the `button` in your dialog.

UPDATE (sorry no code tag, i update from  phone)

You should use R.layout.dialog instead of R.id.dialog in your setContentView method.

Comment: I appreciate your answer because I'm sure i'd face this problem later. I'm gonna edit/update my question, i forgot to say i got the exception on the line "dialog.setContentView(R.id.dialog);"

Comment: Thanks :) I think it should be R.layout.dialog

Comment: Oh boy, sometimes I feel embarassed because of the kind of questions I ask. Well, I can always say that I'm young and still careless :S

Comment: I think theres no problem with your question, you showed what you tried and provided good code :) Its just a small mistake, that we sometimes did